# Regex to remove ANSI escape sequences from script output

Tags: regex, sed, vim

I'm trying to write a regex to remove all that starts with '[' and ends with 'm' or ';' so that the following script will be purged of all its special chars:

```
Script started on 2023-09-16 10:06:45-04:00 [TERM="xterm-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/1" COLUMNS="204" LINES="55"]
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^M^[[0m^[Desktop^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDocuments^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDownloads^[[0m  ^[[01;34mmarkdown^[[0m  ^[[01;34mMusic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mnotes^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPictures^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPublic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mscripts^[[0m  ^[[01;34msnap^[[0m  ^[[01;34mTemplates^[[0m  typescript  ^[[01;34mVideos^[[0m^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^M^[[0m^[Desktop^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDocuments^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDownloads^[[0m  ^[[01;34mmarkdown^[[0m  ^[[01;34mMusic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mnotes^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPictures^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPublic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mscripts^[[0m  ^[[01;34msnap^[[0m  ^[[01;34mTemplates^[[0m  typescript  ^[[01;34mVideos^[[0m^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^M^[[0m^[Desktop^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDocuments^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDownloads^[[0m  ^[[01;34mmarkdown^[[0m  ^[[01;34mMusic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mnotes^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPictures^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPublic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mscripts^[[0m  ^[[01;34msnap^[[0m  ^[[01;34mTemplates^[[0m  typescript  ^[[01;34mVideos^[[0m^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ exit^M
^[[?2004l^Mexit^M

Script done on 2023-09-16 10:06:49-04:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]
```

for now my command looks something like:

```
%s:/^M\|^G\|^[//g | %s/\[01;34m//g | %s/\[01;32m//g
```

and while I'm still working on it, it removes a good chunk but it's quite repetitive which defeats the purpose of regex

Anyone know a quicker way to remove every substring that starts with '[' and ends with 'm' or ';'?

Output should look like:

```
Script started on 2023-09-16 10:06:45-04:00 [TERM="xterm-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/1" COLUMNS="204" LINES="55"]
matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  markdown  Music  notes  Pictures  Public  scripts  snap  Templates  typescript  Videos 
matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  markdown  Music  notes  Pictures  Public  scripts  snap  Templates  typescript  Videos 
matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  markdown  Music  notes  Pictures  Public  scripts  snap  Templates  typescript  Videos 
matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ exit
exit

Script done on 2023-09-16 10:06:49-04:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please show what your sample text should become.

Comment: Have you tried to configure your terminal / environment / commands in a way that don't produce ANSI escape sequences in the first place?

Comment: I haven't, do you have a resource or link for that?

Comment: https://no-color.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should remove all ANSI codes, assuming you have properly constructed codes (escape character is literal and not its printable representation `^[`):

```
%s/\e\[[0-9;?]*[a-zA-Z]
```

The same can be done with sed:

```
sed 's,\x1B\[[0-9;?]*[a-zA-Z],,g'
```

Comment: Great, after adding the '?', the output looks like: ]0;matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  markdown  Music  notes  Pictures  Public  scripts  snap  Templates  typescript  Videos
]0;matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  markdown  Music  notes  Pictures  Public  scripts  snap  Templates  typescript  Videos
]0;matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  markdown  Music  notes  Pictures  Public  scripts  snap  Templates  typescript  Videos
]0;matt@SERENITY: ~matt@SERENITY:~$ exit
exit, still ']0m;' left

Comment: Somehow the regex didn't capture ']0m;'

Comment: yeah i figured, the end result to remove everything unnecessary was: %s/\e\[[0-9;?]*[a-zA-Z] | %s/\]0m;//g | %s/^M\|^G\|^[//g

Comment: btw could you confirm my understanding of the following line: [0-9;?]*[a-zA-Z] does this include all chars in the range [0-9;?] up to any alphabet char, in which case it'll also include that alpha char?

Comment: Yes, and yes, it will also include that last alpha character.